# What is the difference between Turing-reducibility and m-reducibility?

Tags: logic, computability

The set $A$ is many-one reducible (m-reducible) to the set $ B $ if there is a
total computable function $f$ such that $x ∈ A $ iff $f(x) ∈ B$  for all $x$.

We shall write $A ≤_{m} B$

Let be $A, B \subset \mathbb{N}$

is it true that $A \leq_{m} B \implies A\leq_{T}B$?

Where $A\leq_{T}B$ is that $A$ is Turing-reducible to the set B.

If it is true, why do the mathematicians use more Turing-reducibility than m-reducibility? Can you give me some counterexample of two sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{N}$  where $A\leq_{T}B$ and $\neg (A\leq_{m}B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\le_m$ implies $\le_T$. The converse, however, is **false**, so they are truly different things.

An easy example of this is supplied by the following: any set is Turing equivalent to its complement, but in general a set need not be many-one reducible to its complement. For example, if $C$ is a non-recursive recursively enumerable set, then $C$ is *not* many-one reducible to its complement.

This helps motivate $\le_T$ as opposed to $\le_m$: intuitively, a set has exactly as much information as its complement, just "twisted around" (in a very computable way); $\le_T$ reflects this but $\le_m$ doesn't. (That said, there are also situations where $\le_m$ is more natural.)

---

Incidentally, it's worth noting that there are other reducibilities strictly between $\le_m$ and $\le_T$, such as **truth-table reducibility** $\le_{tt}$ (with respect to which a set is equivalent to its complement).

Comment: Do you know the relation between $\leq_{c}$ and the others $\leq_{T}, \leq_{m}$ and $\leq_{tt}$?

Where $A\leq_{c}B$ iff $ A\in L[B]$.

Comment: @NicolásCastro $\le_c$ is vastly, vastly, *vastly* broader. Not only does $\le_T$ (and hence $\le_m,\le_{tt},$ etc.) imply $\le_c$, it's consistent with ZFC that there is only one $\le_c$-degree at all! They're just not on the same playing field at all.

Comment: What is $\le_c$?

Comment: @user170039 Relative [constructibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe): $x\le_cy$ iff $x\in L[y]$. This is a ridiculously coarse reducibility (from the perspective of computability theory at least).